# How to pick specific elements from a jsondecode in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, decode, google-distancematrix-api

I am planning to take distance and time from a JSON list provided by google distance API however I have no idea how to specifically take the elements, here's the code I use to get the json

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDistance(
  String Origin, String Destination) async {
final String url =
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$Origin&destinations=$Destination&key=$key';
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
//print("JSON:"+json['rows'].toString());
var results = {
  'info':json['rows'],
};
return results;}
```

printing results will give,

```
"rows": [

        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "17.6 km",
                        "value": 17574
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "27 mins",
                        "value": 1642
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "12.8 km",
                        "value": 12840
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "22 mins",
                        "value": 1323
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "12.7 km",
                        "value": 12693
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "29 mins",
                        "value": 1753
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "1 m",
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "1 min",
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "25.1 km",
                        "value": 25135
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "36 mins",
                        "value": 2160
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "40.1 km",
                        "value": 40107
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "48 mins",
                        "value": 2858
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "26.2 km",
                        "value": 26187
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "34 mins",
                        "value": 2048
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "1 m",
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "1 min",
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "7.7 km",
                        "value": 7690
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "17 mins",
                        "value": 1046
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "31.5 km",
                        "value": 31482
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "42 mins",
                        "value": 2548
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "9.7 km",
                        "value": 9726
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "22 mins",
                        "value": 1298
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "1 m",
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "1 min",
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
```

I only need the distance and duration however I have no idea how to take it, since I tried using,

```
var results = {
  'info':json['rows'][0][elements],
};
```

and it only take the 1st elements. I am planning to make a distance between multiple points, I have rearrange the points so I can take certain results from the matrix,
[image]

I am still new in json decoding and have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDistance(
  String Origin, String Destination) async {
final String url =
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$Origin&destinations=$Destination&key=$key';
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
//print("JSON:"+json['rows'].toString());
var results = {
  'info':json['rows'][0]['elements'],
};
return results;}
```

Please check with updated code.